# Filtering out a chemical dataset according to information in columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I'm working with a chemical dataset and I was wondering about the smartest way to do the following thing. My dataset looks something like this:

```
formula      Temperature (Kelvin)      (Physical) Property Value
  CO2             298                       5
  CO2             298                       7.6
  CO2             300                       3.2
  NaCl            300                       3.4
  NaCl            296                       1.4
  H2O             298                       7.2
  H2O             298                       8.3
  H2O             293                       6.4
  ZnO             300                       3.10
  ZnO             290                       1.2
  FeO             295                       4.6
  FeO             290                       3.6
```

Given that *Room Temperature* := 298K,

what I would like to accomplish is to **filter** the original dataset in order to have only values reported with *Room Temperature* when it is available, and if there's no value reported at room temperature, I would like to keep the **closest** value to the room temperature that is available. According to what I would like to achieve, the sample initial dataset above would become something like

```
formula      Temperature (Kelvin)      (Physical) Property Value
  CO2             298                       5
  CO2             298                       7.6
  NaCl            300                       3.4
  H2O             298                       7.2
  H2O             298                       8.3
  ZnO             300                       3.10
  FeO             295                       4.6
```

Maybe I should use a `lambda` expression?

Any suggestions on how to achieve something like this?

Many thanks,

James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can first filter the "good" ones, i.e., those that have temp 298 K. Then we can sort the remaining rows with respect to their distance to 298 K and then drop the duplicates to keep only the closests. We lastly merge good ones and these:

```
# room temp in K
rt = 298

# taking those that have `rt` K temp
good_ones = df[df["Temperature (Kelvin)"].eq(rt)]
good_names = good_ones.formula.unique()

# getting others
others = df[~df.formula.isin(good_names)]

# filtering others according to distance to `rt`
sorter = lambda s: s.sub(rt).abs()
others_filtered = (others
                     .sort_values("Temperature (Kelvin)", key=sorter)
                     .drop_duplicates("formula", keep="first"))

# merging them all
result = pd.concat([good_ones, others_filtered]).sort_index(ignore_index=True)
```

to get

```
>>> result

  formula  Temperature (Kelvin)  (Physical) Property Value
0     CO2                   298                        5.0
1     CO2                   298                        7.6
2    NaCl                   300                        3.4
3     H2O                   298                        7.2
4     H2O                   298                        8.3
5     ZnO                   300                        3.1
6     FeO                   295                        4.6
```

---

There's also the `apply` way:

```
def filter_temp(gr):
    # get he temp column and a bool series where it equals `rt`
    temps = gr["Temperature (Kelvin)"]
    rt_temps = temps.eq(rt)
    # does any temp match `rt`?
    if rt_temps.any():
        # then return the locations it matches
        return gr[rt_temps]
    else:
        # otherwise return the closest one
        return gr.loc[[gr.temps.sub(rt).abs().idxmin()]]

result = (df.groupby("formula", as_index=False, group_keys=False)
            .apply(filter_temp).sort_index(ignore_index=True))
```

Comment: Why do we need two cases? Couldn't we just have one condition where we look for the closest value to 298 (which would sometimes be 298)?

Comment: If a group has a matching temp, then the matching temp's locations are kept *and* others are discarded. But if no match is found, only one record is kept. Not sure if these many & one kind of keeping records can be done in one shot. I couldn't, anyway. @le_camerone

Comment: Ok I've started reading your solution: why do you specify good_names and drop duplicated formulas with 298? I still need to retain duplicates at 298 since the physical property associated may be different.

Comment: @JamesArten good ones (those that have at least one 298) are retained as is; it is the others that `drop_duplicates` drops.

Comment: @JamesArten I treat the dataframe in 2 parts: first part is those formulae that have at least one matching temperature to 298. Second part is what remains else (found with looking at the formulae that don't have "good names"). Then I filter them separately and concat at the end.

Comment: @JamesArten That part addresses the formulae *other than* CO2 and H20. For those entries, we sort them with respect the temperature's distance to 298. Then since you need only 1 entry per formula, we drop the duplicated formulas to only have the smallest distance having entry per formula. By *"As it is, it won't run for me"*, do you mean code doesn't run or you don't fully see what's going on? I tried to explain but maybe you can run this part by part to see what each is doing...

Comment: Ok I almost got everything, thanks! ^^ (Still reading it again I will ask minor clarifiements just in case ^^) And yes the code issue was me bad indenting the code you displayed

Comment: If now as a final thing I wanted to take the median of the physical property values corresponding to duplicated compositions at the same temperature, would it be straightforward? maybe doing something like  
result.groupby('formula').apply(lambda x: x.median())

Comment: @JamesArten You want to have 1 record for those duplicated ones, right? i.e., for CO2 and H20? Then yes you can go for `result.groupby("formula", sort=False).median()` which is similar to yours but we don't change the order of appearance of formulae by `sort=False` and using the ready-function `median` on groupby instead of applying.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235223/discussion-between-james-arten-and-mustafa-aydin).

Answer (score 2):

The idea here is to group the rows by `formula`. Each group is then filtered to keep all rows with the required room temperature if any or the unique row with the closest temperature. Let's define this function:

```py
def temperature_filter(df, room_temp, temp_col="Temperature (Kelvin)"):
   if room_temp in df[temp_col].values:
       return df[df[temp_col] == room_temp]
   else:
       return df.loc[[abs(df[temp_col] - room_temp).idxmin()]]
```

It only remains to apply this function to each group:

```py
ROOM_TEMP = 298
df.groupby("formula", sort=False).apply(temperature_filter, ROOM_TEMP).droplevel("formula")
```

Note that `temperature_filter` has been written with clarity in mind, bun can also be included as a lambda function to reach a one-line solution!

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
df['val'] = np.abs(df['Temperature (Kelvin)'] - 298)
df = df.sort_values(['formula', 'val'], ascending=[True, True])
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='formula', keep="first")
```

To make sure you don't lose any 298 duplicates another solution is:

```
df['val'] = np.abs(df['Temperature (Kelvin)'] - 298)
the_298s = df[df['Temperature (Kelvin)'] == 298]
others = df[df['Temperature (Kelvin)'] != 298]
others = others.sort_values(['formula', 'val'], ascending=[True, True])
others = others.drop_duplicates(subset='formula', keep="first")
the_298s_formulas = the_298s.formula.unique()
others = others[~ others.formula.isin(the_298s_formulas)]
final_df = the_298s.append(others)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def filter_closest_to_rt(df, rt=298):
    df['tmrt'] = df['Temperature (Kelvin)'].sub(rt).abs()
    return df[df['tmrt'] == df.groupby('formula')['tmrt'].transform('min')].drop(columns='tmrt')

filter_closest_to_rt(df)
```

```
   formula  Temperature (Kelvin)  (Physical) Property Value
0      CO2                   298                        5.0
1      CO2                   298                        7.6
3     NaCl                   300                        3.4
4     NaCl                   296                        1.4
5      H2O                   298                        7.2
6      H2O                   298                        8.3
8      ZnO                   300                        3.1
10     FeO                   295                        4.6
```

Comment: Good idea if for each group we want to keep all rows which temperature is the closest to the desired one. But according to the question, we want to keep only one row when the target temperature is not reached.